# Pickers Material ui, error displayed ONLY in english language

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, momentjs

Into my react application I'm using material UI pickers and I want that the errors will be displayed in Italian language. The calendar it's ok with the Italian and I specify it in this way thanks to moment:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/it'
```

but this declaration seems not working for pickers. Can someone help me?

[image]

***updated with working example =>***
https://60qb9.csb.app/

Comment: add a working example

Comment: After some try, found it seems not related to MUI localization, kindly add full code or an online demo would be preferred. It may also depend on the lib you are using

Comment: @Dekel added! https://60qb9.csb.app/

Comment: @keikai added! https://60qb9.csb.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `invalidDateMessage` prop of the `KeyboardDatePicker`:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  disableToolbar
  variant="inline"
  format="MM/dd/yyyy"
  margin="normal"
  id="date-picker-inline"
  label="Date picker inline"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{
    "aria-label": "change date"
  }}
  invalidDateMessage="Computer says no"
/>
```

Live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-picker-set-invalid-date-message-rn2in

Comment: Just to add if someone wants to change the max date error message then you need to use 'maxDateMessage' field.